# Django Python how to take data from another sessionid cookie?

Tags: python, django, session

So I'm working with django python, and on every new browser I get a new sessionid for my cookie, every sessionid got a unique session database itself. I'm looking for a way to grab data from other sessionid's if possible.

Example:
Im on my site, in 2 different browsers.

Each browser got a unique sessionid cookie, therefore a unique session database.

(cookie examples (not real or valid)):

Chrome: a7363dc Firefox: a3621bcz

In chrome, I got request.session["foo"] Set too "bar"

In Firebox, I got request.session["foo"] set too "zoo"

Is there a way I can like var = request.session[a3621bcz]['foo'] so it takes the value of session "foo" in firefox? (lets say i perform this in chrome)

Or alternatively, is there any way I can make every sessionid cookie the same all the time for everybody? so that everyone has the same access to the request.session["elm"] elements?

Like example: wether im on chrome, firefox, or even at starbucks on my chromebook, when I search for the request.session['foo'] it returns "bar" no matter which one im logging in from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the sessions of a given session id with:

```
from django.conf import settings
from importlib import import_module

engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
sessionstore = engine.SessionStore

session = sessionstore(session_key)
```

with *`session_key`* the session key (so here `'a3621bcz'`). You thus can then access it with `session['foo']`. That being said, it is probably better *not* to mix sessions. Django makes use of session middleware to make accessing the *relevant* session more convenient, and thus prevent "leaking" sessions variables between two sessions.

Comment: Just to clarify, lets say i'm in my chrome browser with sessionid: a7363dc , if I do the code above (session = sessionstore('a3621bcz')) Then If I do var1 = session["foo"], it will give me the value of the session foo for my firefox sessionid? ('a3621bcz')

Comment: @jasonmzx: yes.